# C# NFC Emulator Android

Tags: c#, android, nfc

Wondering if anyone is aware of a C# package that enables reading then emulating via NFC.

This would be for a simple RFID card that basically just stores a UID. No encryption.

I have searched here, on github etc and there are some readers/writers out there but nothing to emulate. There is already an app on Play Store to do this, NFC Tools, but there are some concerns there with privacy and storing/sharing information. I would just like to create my own app so I don't have to worry about this.

I always forget my swipe card at home and was looking to make a quick c# (all i know) app to just use my phone to get in the door at work.

Thx

Comment: Searching for tools/libraries is off-topic on SO. As a side note cloning keys of all sorts may be illegal or at very least *very questionable* unless it is your own company...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to emulate the UID on Android.

Android's Host Card Emulation works at a higher level protocol than the UID and Android for security purposes generates a random UID at the low level which you have no control of.

On Android you can really only emulate a Type 4 card using the ISO 7816 protocols (which allows you to emulate the even higher level NDEF data format, this is what NFC-Tools App is doing).

Note that using a UID for access equals no security at all as there are a lot of Chinese clone cards where the UID is programmable (or there are some card formats where the UID is designed as programmable).

The UID in NFC is not designed to be Unique Globally, just most likely to be unique when multiple cards are presented to a reader at the same time to prevent card clash. It is not the same as true RFID UID's

Comment: Thanks! Won't waste my time trying this then.